# Suppose that X is a random variable. E(X) = µ and Var(X) = σ^2 and let c be a constant. What is E[(X − c)^2]=?

Tags: probability

I want to know how it can be solved? one solution i did is:

VarX=Var(X−c)
VarX=E(X−c)2−(E(X−c))2 E(X−c)2=VarX+(E(X−c))2 E(X−c)2=σ2+(μ−c)2

is this answer correct?

Comment: Why did you remove LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in multiple other questions before.  Please search the site.

That said, it is straightforward to do the decomposition of squares:

$$(X-c)^2 = (X-\mu+\mu-c)^2 = (X-\mu)^2 + 2(\mu-c)(X-\mu) + (\mu-c)^2,$$ therefore $$\operatorname{E}[(X-c)^2] = \operatorname{E}[(X-\mu)^2] + 2(\mu-c)\operatorname{E}[X-\mu] + (\mu-c)^2$$ and because $\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu$, we immediately obtain $$\operatorname{E}[(X-c)^2] = \sigma^2 + (\mu-c)^2.$$

Your work is poorly formatted and incomprehensible.

Comment: First, sorry for bad format,
Well, thank you for the answer i also see this answer before but i afraid whether its correct or not.